# Using Socket.IO to show object count within Compound.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm testing out Socket.IO for a new project that uses Compound.js (built on node.js/Express.js), but I've come across a problem. I've managed to get the basics working and the following message works fine:

Server-side JS (applicationname/config/initializers/socketio.js):

```
var sio = require('socket.io');
var http = require('http');
var activeClients = 0;

module.exports = function (compound) {
    var app = compound.app;
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    compound.server = server;
    var io = compound.io = sio.listen(server);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        activeClients +=1;

        var connections = setInterval(function () {
            socket.emit('news', { clients: activeClients });
        }, 1000);

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            activeClients -= 1;
            io.sockets.emit('user disconnected');
            clearInterval(connections);
        });
    });
}
```

Front-end JS (applicationname/public/index.html):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');

      function msgReceived(msg){
        $clientCounter.html(msg.posts);
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $clientCounter = $("#client_count");
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
            msgReceived(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
          });
      });
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do now is get the number of posts that have been made on the server. I used a default scaffold to generate the Posts method, controller and views.

How do I now find the total number of posts and pass that value to the server-side JS?

Answer (score 0):

Simply count the number of emits on the server side and send that?

```
    ...
    var emits = 0;
    var connections = setInterval(function () {
        emits++;
        socket.emit('news', { clients: activeClients , num_messages: emits});
    }, 1000);

    ...
```

Or create a specific message that can be polled from the client

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help. I have a Posts Model (think blog posts), and want to count the number of posts to show on the front-end, so that when someone creates a new post the new number of total posts gets pushed to all users. I don't know how counting emits will help with that?

Comment: you are right - that wont help than. However your code is misleading somehow. imo all of this has nothing to do with socket.io, or does it? Actually without knowing how you store your blog posts ... what about simply retrieving them from the persistence store that you are certainly using and simply count them and then emitting this number?

Comment: Well, that is the actual question itself - last line, "How do I now find the total number of posts and pass that value to the server-side JS?". I can't figure out both sides, hence the question.

Comment: Again: read the number of posts from the persistent store and transfer it via the socket.emit("news", {number_of_posts: readFromPersistentStore()}); to the client.